# How to install scikit-learn version 0.21.2?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I trained an ML algorithm on my desktop at an internship (which is ending soon.) I've delivered the code to my supervisor. The code crashes (on his machine) because his machine runs scikit-learn version 0.18.1, whereas mine runs v 0.21.2

I've tried:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

and

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.21.2
```

Here's the error message:

```
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.18.1
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'scikit-learn'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

For context, we're both using anaconda distribution and installed during the same week. I'm not sure how this issue originated or how to correct it.

Comment: Use virtual environments

Comment: So create an environment and use the exact same command, yes?

Comment: Make sure that a) you are both actually using the `python` binary that came from the anaconda installation (esspecially on your supervisors computer) b) to use `conda` to update packages that came shipped with the anaconda distribution. If neither helps, then use a virtualk environment like suggeted by Dan (`conda create -n <somename> scikit-learn=0.21.2`)